# Eliminating a free variable in a linear programming problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Consider the following linear model.

\begin{align}
\min&\quad z = c^{t}x\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad Ax = b\\
&\quad e^{t} x = 1 \\
&\quad x_{i}\geqslant0 \quad \forall i \in \{1,...,n-1\}
\end{align}

where $b, c \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A_{ij} = 1$ if $ i = j$ or $j = n$ and $A_{ij} = 0$ otherwise. Finally, $e^{t}_{i} = 1$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ and $x_n$ is a free variable.

Use the $e^{t} x = 1$ restriction to get rid of $x_n$. Can you do the same if $x_n$ is not a free variable?

---

I've tried solving it for $n = 3$ for simplicity, so we have $ A =\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0& 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right) $

And we get the following restrictions:
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_3 = b_1 \\
x_2 + x_3 = b_2 \\
x_3 = b_3 \\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1 \\
\end{align}

Which leads to

\begin{align}
x_1 = b_1 - b_3 \\
x_2 = b_2 - b_3 \\
x_1 + x_2 = 1 - b_3
\end{align}

Now if I understand this right we've gotten rid of $x_3$ since it's forced to be equal to $b_3$ and we can replace that in all the equations.

I think this is probably wrong though since $x_3$ being a free variable is not involved in any point. Furthermore, if we let $x_3 \geq 0$ I can find no contradiction and it feels like I'm just moving symbols around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the constraint $x_3=b_3$ holds, then we can replace it everywhere (after all we need to satisfy this condition in the feasible set also). Furthermore, if $x_3\geq 0$ and $b_3<0$, we will have a contradiction, else not. So there is no question of moving symbols around, the optimization makes sense.